# Composition vs. Inheritance

Tags: oop, inheritance, uml, composition, class-diagram

For a UML Class Diagram, if a class A has a composition relationship with another class B, does it work like inheritance? I know that the class A cannot exist without class b but does class A inherit the attributes and methods from class B?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Composition over inheritance

In OO design, a common advice is to prefer [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).  This might mislead to think that there is a relation between these two different concepts:

- Inheritance is about a relation between classes.
- Composition is a about relations between objects of classes.

Even more misleading: the "composition" used in the general OO literature corresponds in general to a [simple UML association](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html?context=class-diagrams) and is not to be understood as restrictive as the UML "composition".

### Inheritance is about generalisation and specialisation

If class `D` inherits from  `B`,  it means that `D` [specialises a more general concept](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/generalization.html?context=class-diagrams) `B`:

- It has all the properties and operations of `B` (without need to repeat them in the diagram),
- It can have additional properties and operations that are not relevant for `B`, and
- It can perform some operations of `B` differently.
- Any object of class `D` is also an object of class `B` for its full lifetime. This is why we speak of a "***Is a***" relationship.

Naive example (just for the illustration):

[image]

### Composition is about association of objects of very different classes

If class `B` "composes" (has a [composition association](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/composition.html?context=class-diagrams) with) `C`, it means that the `B` object can be associated with different `C` objects over its lifetime. Anf that objects of class `C` :

- always belong to a `B` object that owns it.  This is why we sometimes speak of a "***has a***" relationship;
- will not survive its owning `B` object .

**Caution: UML composition is about an exclusive ownership.  In the OO literature, the term "composition" often refers to weaker associations without any ownership or even exclusivity.**

Naive example (just for the illustration):

[image]

Comment: Even the good quality of your answer I have few remarks. The composition for the engine and well is really not a good choice, we know all a car car be destructed while some parts of it survive including engine / wheel. Also there are more and more hybrid cars having several engines including electric so multiplicity 1 is old fashion ^^, and then you can add *HybridCar* inheriting *ElectricalCar* and *GazolineCar*. And finally I know they are cars including old ones having 3 wheels (the fifth is to replace one of the 4 probably).

Comment: I precise I do not DV your answer (nor the other one), I say in case that happens later, as for the two other answers including mine (even I think I know who did for mine ...)

Comment: @bruno thanks for this comment.  I should have warned that these are "naive examples". , since I would not use inheritance in real life for electrical cars either because I'd rather go to a composite pattern or a entity-component-system.  By the way, and since you're an expert:  does UML address in its semantic the case of a former component?  Suppose I have 5 wheels, remove them (one by one because of my 4..5) to add them to another car, and add new wheels to my car: whoudn't this be valid ?

Comment: that is a good remark, for both engine and wheel the lower multiplicity must be 0 to allow to remove some of them, for instance a car is still a car even not able to run because having no wheels ^^ So a priori the right multiplicity for engine is "0..*" or its shortcut "*" without limiting the max number, and for wheel "0..5" supposing 5 the max possible. After it is possible to add constraints about number of engine/wheels to be able to run

Comment: Interestingly the lower diagram has a flaw often repeated. You class  `Car` is actually the `Chassis` while only the whole construct can be called `Car`. UMLs possibility to show the existence of such a construct are actually poor and often lead to confusion (about aggregation).

Comment: @qwerty_so This is what I tried to explain in my first comment to Bruno: in real life, for real cars, I’d myself go for composite or ECS. However there are plenty of cases where such a simplified and naive model is largely sufficient, for example online car configurators or traffic simulation (e.g finding out impact on urban CO2 emissions if electrical cars reach 20% and trafic lights discourage some heavily frequented streets). It is therefore a good thing that UML agnostically allows to model such a simplified reality if it fits the purpose ;-)

Comment: That's where we are back to Einstein: as simple as possible, but not simpler. Can be stuff for looong discussions :-)

Comment: Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance and composition are two different concepts. If they were the same there would not be the need to have different notation.

- Compostion is about lifetime of objects. Composed elements will be destroyed the moment the owner is destroyed. But each instance can (and likely will) be something completely different than the composing object. The well known example is a car: When you shredder a car its composed wheels will be shreddered as well. Only if you detach them beforehand they can live on.
- Inheritance means that instances will have operations and attributes on their own defined in the parent class. This works in each single instance. There's no good real worl example for inheritance (genes work different and inherited assets also don't help here).

Answer (score 0):

> if a class A has a composition relationship with another class B

Lets suppose you mean `A <*>--- B` or  `A <*>---> B` rather than the reverse (`B <*>--- A` or  `B <*>---> A`), because this is not very clear in your question.

> class A cannot exist without class b

It is not about *classes* but about *instances* of these classes, and *B* can have instances independently of that composition, so the limited life is not for all instances of *B*.

> does it work like inheritance? does class A inherit the attributes and methods from class B ?

No.

*A* inherits *B* means *A* **is a** *B*, this is absolutely not the case having `A <*>--- B` or  `A <*>---> B` or the reverse.

Then independently of the visibility of the operations you cannot apply the operations of *A* to the instances of *B* nor the reverse, except of course if you also have an inheritance more that the composition.

About the attributes of *B* depending on the way the composition is implemented it is possible they are part of the corresponding instance of *A*, this is the case for instance in C++ not using a pointer for the composition. But anyway that does not means these attributes of *B* are attributes of *A*, to access them it is needed to first access of the instance of *B* though the compositions, and that also supposes an instance of *A* has the right to directly access these attributes of *B*, so they are typically *public*.

Note also you can have `A<*>--->B<*>--->A` etc and fortunately that does implies *A* inherits *B* and *B* inherits *A* which is impossible