# Sharing implementation of interfaces in C#

Tags: c#, interface

I have some interfaces that need some simple implementation, but I have a handful of them, like for instance (not actual code, just example)

```
interface ISelectable
{
  public bool IsSelected;
  public void Select();
}

public class Selectable : ISelectable
{
  public bool IsSelected {get;set}
  public void Select()=> IsSelected = true;
}
```

Then I might have `IStorable`, which allows storing stuff in the database, like:

```
public interface IStorable
{
    public void Store();
    ...
}
public class Storable : IStorable
{
    private stuff...
    public void Store() { storing code }
}
```

The question is:

I have

- elements that are `IStorable` but not `ISelectable`,
- elements that are `ISelectable` and no `IStorable`,
- and elements that are both.

Actually... I have MORE of these classes. So the combinations grow fast.

As far as I know, the only way to share the code is to have a base class implement the interface, then your class inherits from this base class. Like:

```
public class GameCard : Selectable { ....
```

But this would mean that the only way to have a class that inherits the code for `Selectable`, and the code for Storable is to have a base class doing both, something like `public class StorableAndSelectable: IStorable, ISelectable` But this makes no sense, especially when you want to have different storing methods...

What's the proper way to have your classes share the implementation code of the interfaces it implements? Having the implementation for each of them in one file, and feeding this "file" to all classes that need it?

Comment: Modern C# allows default implementations in interfaces; Older versions support extension methods. Both let you write methods that don't exist in the actual implementing classes.

Comment: You can use composition instead of inheritance [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62209348/composition-vs-inheritance)

Comment: you may have a look on the decorator-pattern. Basically that is about "my class is storable, and selectable, and draggable".

Comment: I dont like the composition idea because I still want to have List<ISelectable> for instance. That's super convenient...  And this list will contain a variety of cards and tokens in the game.

Comment: My proposal is using a chain of responsibility pattern. Multiple inheritance is not allowed in C#.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider if inheritance is the correct approach for such simple properties. There are some possible alternatives. Using inheritance to include functionality is called *implemention inheritance* and is generally frowned upon. For simple stuff like this it provides little benefit, and for more complicated logic it ties the derived class to the base class to tightly.

To store an object I would probably suggest the [repository pattern](https://codewithshadman.com/repository-pattern-csharp/), that way you do not need a special interface.

To handle things like if a object is selected, the easiest option is probably just to have a settable property in the interface: `bool IsSelected {get;set;}`. This is trivially implementable by all derived classes, there is no real advantage of a implementation of just that interface, at least not outside of testing/dummy objects.

In some cases you can use a `Func<T, bool>` to describe how to determine if some arbitrary type is selected. In some cases it might be useful to use composition, i.e. use a separate class to describe selection, and have your game objects contain a property of this class.

Comment: Having fields on each class or having composition don't allow me to have List<ISelectable> that is super convenient. When the server wants the client (player) to choose what token to discard, it sents a list of items (cards, tokens, points) that can be choosen upon. Then the client returns one of the ISelectables that was selected by the user.   This is just one example. There might be Flipable for tokens that can flip, ITokenContainer for cards that can hold tokens over it. And for all of those would be good to have a way to just declare that your thing is a token, and is flipable, and so on

Comment: Sounds like you are developing a game. I will concur with @jonasH here and point you to ECS, which - again - is not inheritance.

Comment: @javirs You don't really need a interface for that, you could send a list of `object` and receive the selected object back. If you are writing a game you probably want some base type for a 'gameobject',  but that would probably do also other things. The best solution will depend on things not coverted in the OP, but if you find yourself wanting to inherit from multiple classes, or have a combinatorial explosion of interfaces, you really need to take a hard look at your design. I would recommend reading [Wizards And Warriors](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/)

Comment: I'm reading into the ECS thing. I'm liking it so far :)  Wizards will come afterward. Thanks a lot for all the directions!

Answer (score 0):

Starting from C# 8.0 you can have default method implementation in interface definition

```
interface IA
{
    void M() { WriteLine("IA.M"); }
}
class C : IA { } // OK

IA i = new C();
i.M(); // prints "IA.M"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods

According to your classes you can do something like this

```
interface ISelectable
{
  public bool IsSelected;
  public void Select() => IsSelected = true;
}
```

Comment: I'm kind of sad about this, hehehe. This solves my current problem because the implementations are so simple, that will suffice. But what about changing the storage method from MySQL to something else.. Will mean I have to rewrite the IStorable or have all my classes implement a new IAzureStorable instead of the existing IStorable. This is a very bad SOLID design…