# Trying to understand the fundamental difference on something simple here with python inheritance vs i don't even know what to call this

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass

I am trying to understand multiple inheritance vs this other thing i am doing.
I don't even know what to call it. First let me explain this other thing. What is this even called? It seems to work really well without giving me a headache unlike inheritance.

```
    class my_pets():
      def __init__():
      pass
      self.mycat = cats()
    
    class cats():
      def __init__():
      self.cats_name = bruno
```

So i dont know what that is called but it works well. I have been calling it a sub_objected incorrectly in my head. I know that is not inheritance.
I am utterly mystified with inheritance. Mainly the when to use it verse when to do what i did above. If i wrote the above with inheritance i would of done.

```
    class my_pets(cats):
      def __init__():
      super(cats,self).__init__(cats_name)
    
    
    
    class cats():
      def __init__(cats_name):
      self.cats_name = cats_name
```

So i don't understand the difference and when to do one or the other.
Can someone even tell me what this is called?

I appreciate the suggested thread and i had seen that previously. So that post is specific to UML drawings. Is composition what it is called then? That seems very specific to UML

Also, the answer still baffles me
If you google any search on inheritance all the examples lead to something that can be easily done with this other approach. The typical examples.
Mom, dad , child
pet, cat , dog etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composition vs. Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62209348/composition-vs-inheritance)

Comment: The canonical rule of thumb is that inheritance is used to represent "is a" relationships, such as "a cat **is a** mammal", whereas composition is used to express "has a" relationships, such as "a cat **has a** collar".  Of the two, composition is much more frequently the kind of relationship you want.  Especially in Python, where you don't need inheritance to implement polymorphic behavior.

Comment: Thank you, i have been fighting all day with inheritance and multiple inheritance with super and its just infuriating. Ive lost my whole day. I should of just used "composition" i guess

Answer (score 0):

Its  called super function which is used to give access to the methods of a parent class .Returns a temporary object of a parent class when used .its is mostly used where we overriding (a class drive from another class) like in your code `cats`is a parent class of a `my cats`take a look in my example:

```
class pa_rent:
    classvar1 = "I am a class variable in class A"
    def __init__(self):
    self.var1 = "I am inside class A's constructor"
    self.classvar1 = "Instance var in class A"
    self.special = "Special"

class Child(pa_rent):
    classvar1 = "I am in class B"

    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = "I am inside class B's constructor"
        self.classvar1 = "Instance var in class B"
        super().__init__()
        print(super().classvar1)


a = A()
b = B()

print(b.special, b.var1, b.classvar1)
```

so when we call classvar1, interpreter first checks in instance child's``` child`` variable if its not found then its checks in parent class ```pa_rent`` instance variable .but in this case we  have override and when we call `callssvar1` its gives `Instance var in class B` so, in taht case if we want parent class variable `classvar1` super function `super().__init__` will be used,
I hope its enough for your understanding