# Use the same attributes of one class from the super class python

Tags: python

I have two python classes `A` and `B(A)`. I want to use the variables of `A` in `B`. I mean when I create an instance of A with `a=16`, and an instance of `B` as the code shows, I want to have `b.a=16`. What is the problem here?

I ma sure that this problem is solved but I am not able to find it on Internet.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, a=12) -> None:
        self.a = a


class B(A):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        
a = A(a=16)
b = B()
print(b.a) # why 12 not 16?
```

**EDIT**

I tried to be as simple as possible in my question. I did not meant to do an XY problem (it is the first time I hear about the XY problem, so thanks for pointing out this because I have learnt something).

It turns out that by simplifying my problem, I turned it into an XY problem. Ok, here is my real problem.

I am developing an algorithm to solve an optimization problem in scheduling. I modelled the scheduling system with a python class that is given by my `class A` in the example I showed. This class (the scheduling system) has some parameters: a set of machines, a set of jobs, processing capacities, etc. So, those are the attributes of my class.

Now, I created `class B` to develop the environment of my algorithm to solve the problem. So `class B` should see all the parameters of the scheduling system. Since I am new to OOP, I thought I can do this simply by calling `super().__init__`. But it turns out that this is not possible.

So, to summarize, I want two classes: `class A` for the scheduling system and `class B` for the algorithm environment. `class B` has some methods inside to solve the scheduling problem and should be able to see `class A`'s parameters.

Comment: `a` is different object than `b`. `a` is initialized with value `a=16`, `b` is initialized with `a=12`. Each object has it's own variables they are not shared between different objects.

Comment: `a.a` is an instance variable on `a`, which is of class `A`. `b.a` is an instance variable on `b`, which is of class `B`. But instance variables on `b` never have any relationship with instance variables on `a`, just like the mere existence of `[A(a=16), A(a=12), A(a=8), A(a=4)]` wouldn't have any effect on `foobar = B(a=1)`. This sound like an XY-problem, what are you _actually_ trying to do?

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please explain exactly *why* you are trying to "use the variables of `A` in `B`". What actual problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: I edited my question to address your comments. Thank you for your time.

Comment: That sounds like your `B` instance should accept a reference to a separate `A` instance, instead of trying to inherit from `A`.

Comment: @Jika It sounds like your class `B` should operate on an instance of class `A` via composition, rather than inhering from it (see e.g. [Composition vs. Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62209348/984421) or [Inheritance and Composition: A Python OOP Guide](https://realpython.com/inheritance-composition-python/#composition-in-python)). So the example code would become something like `class B: def __init__(self, a): self.a = a` and then `b = B(a); print(b.a.a)`. Needless to say, this kind of solution will look more appealing with better naming.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the line `b = B()`. This passes the parameter `a` with the default value, which is 12. So, you have two different objects: a, an instance of A that has the attribute `a=16`, and b, an instance of B that has the attribute `a=12`.
To solve the issue, you need to rewrite the line as `b = B(a=16)`.